# Delete array pointer c++ when increase pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have:

```
int *ptr = new int[8];
delete[] ptr;  //  it ok, all ptr is delete;
```

but if I have:

```
int *ptr = new int[8];
ptr++; 
delete[] ptr;
```

My question:

Does `delete[]` delete all `ptr` from `ptr[0]` to `ptr[7]` or just from `ptr[1]` to `ptr[7]`?
And, if it deletes from `ptr[1]` to `ptr[7]`, how does `delete[]` know the real size to delete this time?

Comment: You can't release just a part of an allocation - all or nothing are your only options.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Neither; it's undefined behaviour, which *usually* means it'll crash the program.

The pointer you pass to `delete[]` must be one that was previously returned from `new[]`. No exceptions*. `new[]` returned a pointer to the first element of the array, so you must pass a pointer to the first element of the array to `delete[]`.

* the only exception is that you can pass a NULL pointer, in which case it will do nothing.